# Benford - Dataset with NA strings returns an error in extract.digits

Tags: r, na, missing-data, benfords-law

I've a dataset of macroeconomic data like GDP, inflation, etc... where Rows=different macroeconomic indicators and columns=years

Since some values are missing (ex: the GDP of any country in any year), they are charged as "NA".

When I perform these operations:

```
#
data = read.table("14varnumeros.txt", header = FALSE, sep = "", na.strings = "NA", dec = ".", strip.white = TRUE)

benford(data, number.of.digits = 1, sign = "both", discrete=TRUE, round=3)
#
```

It gives me this error:

> Error in extract.digits(data, number.of.digits, sign, second.order, discrete = discrete, : 
> Data must be a numeric vector

I assume that this is because of the NA strings, but I do not know how to solve it.

Comment: Which package are you getting the `benford` function from? I see at least two candidates on CRAN.

Comment: I'm using the benford.analysis package, NOT the Benford.Tests package. I think the problem is that "data" is not numeric (obviously) because is a list

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue, too. In my case, it wasn't missing data, instead it's because of a quirk in the `extract.digits()` function of the benford.analysis package. The function is checking if the data supplied to it is numeric data, but it does so using `class(dat) != "numeric"` instead of using the `is.numeric()` function.

This produces unexpected errors. Consider the code below:

```r
library(benford.analysis)

dat <- data.frame(v1 = 1:5, v2 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))

benford(dat$v1)          # produces error
```

I've submitted an issue on Github, but you can simply wrap your data in `as.numeric()` and you should be fine.